# Read input file in hex mode in C#

Tags: c#, byte, filestream, binaryreader

File Info: First 4 bytes contains number of records in the file | Next 4 bytes contain length of the first record. After first record again 4 bytes contain length of second record. The entire file is like this. So I have to read the input file and skip first 4 bytes. After that I need to read 4 bytes which will give me length of upcoming record and write out the record in string and repeat the process.

I ma not getting what I am supposed to get. For example:
For 7F CB 00 00, I should get 32715 (which I don nott need, need to skip). Next 4 bytes which is 
00 D3 00 00 00 I should get 211 but I am not getting that.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileStream readStream;
        readStream = new FileStream(singlefilebox.Text,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader readBinary = new BinaryReader(readStream);


        byte inbyte;
        inbyte = readBinary.ReadByte();
        string outbyte;
        while (readBinary.BaseStream.Position < readBinary.BaseStream.Length)
        {
            inbyte = readBinary.ReadByte();
            outbyte = Convert.ToString(inbyte);
        }
```

Comment: What's the actual output of the code ? Comparison with the expected result helps in finding out what's broken

Comment: The byte order may not be interpreted the way you think they are: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: 20300021100127241241 for 7F CB 00 00 00 D3 00 00 7F F1 F1 F1 F5 F8 F4 F3 7F....

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is with how you are doing your output. When you are generating the outbyte, it is being converted to it's decimal notation. For example, CB is converted to 203.

Change the line that generates the outbyte to the following:

```
outbyte = Convert.ToString(String.Format("{0:X}", inbyte));
```

This prints the string representation of the hexadecimal number.

See this answer for more detail about the string formatting. [String.Format for Hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618387/string-format-for-hex)

The bigger issue is that you need to combine the bytes in the proper way. You need to read in each byte, shift it 8 bits, then add the next byte.

```
        string fileName = @"..\..\TestInput.hex";
        FileStream readStream;
        readStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader readBinary = new BinaryReader(readStream);

        byte inbyte;
        string outbyte;
        int value;

        inbyte = readBinary.ReadByte(); // read in the value: 7F in hex , 127 in decimal
        value = inbyte << 8; // shift the value 8 bits to the left: 7F 00 in hex, 32512 in decimal
        inbyte = readBinary.ReadByte(); // read in the next value: CB in hex, 203 in decimal
        value += inbyte; // add the second byte to the first: 7F CB in hex, 32715 in decimal
        Console.WriteLine(value); // writes 32715 to the console
```

Comment: I get your point. However, I want the other way. I want to read input as '7F CB 00 00' give me an out put of 32715. My issue is when I stop at inbyte = readBinary.ReadByte(); I get 127 for 7F and 203 FOR CB. Instead, I want to get 7F first and only convert it to string later at outbyte = Convert.ToString(inbyte);

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking. At the end of my code, value is set to 32715.   0x7f = 127 and 0xCB = 203. To get an outbyte of 32715, you need to have 0x7FCB. The 0x7F is the high order byte.