# Visual Basic Print Hex to text file

Tags: vb.net

I'm using VB-2013. I need to send a string of hex to a text file. Unfortunately I can not send it as raw hex due to another program that needs to read this hex from a text file. I also need to manipulate some of the values to create a checksum. As of now when I write them to the text file they show as decimal. I was wondering how do I convert my hex string into an ASCII equivalent?

This is the main application

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles    Button1.Click
    fileN = TextBox1.Text
    path = ("**************" + fileN + ".txt")

    Dim fs As New FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
    Dim sw As New StreamWriter(fs)
        sw.WriteLine(intV(holder, TextBox2.Text))

    sw.Flush()
    fs.Close()
End Sub
```

This is the fucntion I'm writing

```
  Public Function intV(ByVal arr() As String, r As String)
    i = 0
    textH = Convert.ToInt16(r)
    arr(0) = &H8E
    arr(1) = &H71
    arr(2) = &H7
    arr(3) = &H98
    arr(4) = &HD
    arr(5) = textH
    Do Until arr.Length - 1
        sB = sB + arr(i)
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    arr(6) = sB
    i = 0
    hold = Join(arr, " ")
    Return hold
End Function
```

**EDIT**

Out put in text file with a value of 60 in textbox2

142 113 7 152 13 60 0

Comment: My apologies tag has been removed, Hopefully my current tags are more suiting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [String.Format for Hex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618387/string-format-for-hex)

Comment: Very hard to guess what this code is trying to do, it is rather unique in that every single line of code generates an error.  Put `Option Strict On` at the top of the file and give it another shot.

Comment: Just trying to understand what exactly you're trying to do here.  So you're **NOT** looking for a **string** with "8E 71 07 98 0D 60 0" to be output to your file?  If not, are you looking for maybe [BinaryWriter.Write()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24e33k1w(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hold = String.Join(" ", (From i In arr Select String.Format("{0:X}", i)).ToArray)
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response but unfortunately still returning decimal values.

Comment: Then edit your question to show what output you get.

Comment: `arr` is a string array, while it would need to be an integer array for this to work.

Comment: @Mark: I see that now that you point it out.  I assumed since they were poking ints into it it must be an int array.  Dummy me.

Comment: @Hans: change `arr` to an int array.

Comment: @SamAxe Thank you very much for you help! It is working as needed. Next is to figure out how to properly implement option strict.